# Does event sourcing architecture need to use message queues?

Tags: architecture, message-queue, event-sourcing, event-driven

Consider this simple example. Say you have an events table `TBL_EVENTS` with the ff. columns:

- eventId (int)
- dateTime (datetime)
- eventName (string)
- data (json)

---

Now the ff. event happened:

`$UserService->registerUser();`

A `USER_REGISTERED` event is now stored in `TBL_EVENTS` with the ff. data:

```
eventId: 1
dateTime: 2019-04-30 00:00:00
eventName: USER_REGISTERED
data: {"userId":1, "name":"foo"}
```

---

**1st question:** do event listeners query/listen to `TBL_EVENTS` directly every x seconds or is a message queue needed as to not "bombard" `TBL_EVENTS` with polling requests?

E.g., does `$UserService->registerUser();` pushes an "event" in a separate message queue (e.g., `AWS SQS` ) in addition to `TBL_EVENTS`, then, `$UserService->listener();` polls `SQS` instead of `TBL_EVENTS`? Or, direct polling to `TBL_EVENTS` is used in real world apps?

---

**2nd question:** When `$UserService->listener();` gets a `USER_REGISTERED` event, does it create just one new user to a separate `TBL_USERS` table or does it replay all events the from `0`  to now, thereby creating all users in `TBL_USERS` every time?

Comment: You can always use the native listen/notify functionality of certain databases, like PostgreSQL. Proven, reliable and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

For a similar use-case, my design implemented the following approach -

**[1]** EVENT SOURCE SYSTEM -- *invokes* --> EVENT PROXY -- *writes record* --> EVENT STAGE TABLE

**[2]** EVENT STAGE TABLE -- *triggers* --> DB PROCEDURE -- *writes* --> EVENT QUEUE

**[3]** EVENT HANDLER(S) -- *polls* --> EVENT QUEUE

Such a chain of processing points, helped me maintain a very simple and clean implementation, with flexibility to test unit parts of the system independently.

Now, as for your **Question 2**; I do not understand your need to create users from ground up always. Nevertheless, if that is required for any reason, then with the above approach, you would need another DB procedure (at point # 2), that would iterate the existing rows of the table, and invoke the existing procedure that writes to the event queue.

Another alternative approach that may be considered here is, writing to DB and handling the events in parallel -

**[1]** EVENT SOURCE SYSTEM -- *broadcasts on* --> EVENT CHANNEL

**[2]** DB PROCEDURE -- *listens to* --> EVENT CHANNEL

**[3]** DB PROCEDURE -- *writes to* --> USER TABLE

**[4]** EVENT CONTROLLER -- *listens to* --> EVENT CHANNEL

**[5]** EVENT CONTROLLER -- *invokes* --> EVENT HANDLER(S)

The above approach could offer a declarative (data-driven) approach to registering event handlers, and offer the performance advantage of handling the events in parallel to writing to DB; however the downside is that writing to DB and handling of the event, may require additional efforts should you be expecting a transactional behavior.